# DateTime picker wrong date

Tags: jquery, datetime, picker

minDate is set +3 days from today and min range is also 3 days. Yesterday everything was great, but today it shows not november 3, but december 3. Somehow it jumps one month. What is wrong and how to solve it?

Thank you...

http://jsfiddle.net/ZiNNED/4fa5n7wa/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var today = new Date();

    var minStart = new Date();
    minStart.setDate(today.getDate() + 3);

    var minEnd = new Date(minStart);
    minEnd.setDate(minEnd.getDate() + 3);

    $("#start").datetimepicker({
        format: "Y/m/d H:i",
        dayOfWeekStart: "1",
        value: "12:00",
        inline: true,
        lang: "nl",
        onSelectDate: function (ct) {
            var diff = CalcDiff();

            var minDate = new Date(ct);
            minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 3);

            if (diff > 72)
                var defDate = new Date($("#end").val());

            $("#end").datetimepicker("destroy");
            $("#end").datetimepicker({
                format: "Y/m/d H:i",
                dayOfWeekStart: "1",
                value: "12:00",
                inline: true,
                lang: "nl",
                minDate: minDate,
                defaultDate: defDate || minDate,
                onSelectDate: function (ct) {
                    CalcDiff();
                },
                onSelectTime: function (ct) {
                    CalcDiff();
                }
            }).val(defDate || minDate);

            CalcDiff();
        },
        onSelectTime: function (ct) {
            CalcDiff();
        },
        minDate: minStart,
        defaultDate: minStart
    }).val(minStart);

    $("#end").datetimepicker({
        format: "Y/m/d H:i",
        dayOfWeekStart: "1",
        value: "12:00",
        inline: true,
        lang: "nl",
        minDate: minEnd,
        defaultDate: minEnd,
        onSelectDate: function (ct) {
            CalcDiff();
        },
        onSelectTime: function (ct) {
            CalcDiff();
        }
    }).val(minEnd);

    CalcDiff();
});

function CalcDiff() {
    var start = new Date($("#start").val());
    var end = new Date($("#end").val());

    if (start != null && end != null) { // We have both dates
        var hours = Math.round(Math.abs(end - start) / 36e5);
        $("#difference").val(hours);
    }

    return hours;
}
```

Comment: javascript date is depends on your system, please recheck your pc date, i will suggest to use `moment.js` for this type of calculation

Comment: Everything with my PC date is okay. I checked it in different PC's but it's the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `startDate` instead of `defaultDate`:

```
    startDate: minStart
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4fa5n7wa/13/)